# Generic Class based DetailView returns the same page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building a photo album app. Where users can log in and create categories and add photo posts in those categories.

When post link is clicked it should open the post with the use of DetailView instead, it just loops back to user's post history page with post links

I have been trying to use various methods to filter queryset and return the data but I don't where I am going wrong.

**posts/models.py:**

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        post_title = models.CharField( max_length=30)
        post_message = models.TextField()
        postimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='postimgs/',verbose_name=('post picture'))
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='post_category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.post_title

        def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
            self.post_message_html = misaka.html(self.post_message)
            super().save(*args,**kwargs)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={"username":self.user.username,"pk":self.pk})


        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created_at']
            unique_together = ['user','post_title']
```

**posts/views.py:**

```
    class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DetailView):
        model =models.Post
        select_related = ('user', 'category')

        def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = super().get_queryset()
            return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

**posts/urls.py:**

```
    app_name = 'posts'

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.PostList.as_view(),name='all'),
    url(r'new/$',views.CreatePost.as_view(),name='create'),
    url(r'by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)',views.UserPosts.as_view(),name='for_user'),
    url(r'by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.PostDetail.as_view(),name='single'),
    url(r'delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.DeletePost.as_view(),name='delete'),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**HTML:**

```
      <a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=post.user.username%}">@{{post.user.username}}</a>
        </span>
        <time class="time">
          <a href="{% url 'posts:single' username=post.user.username pk=post.pk %}">
            {{post.created_at}}
          </a>
```

After clicking on the {{post.created_at}} should open the post detail view with details, but it is looping in post list page

Answer (score 1):

your queryset is missing a `comma(',')`

```
def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'),category__categoryname__iexact=self.kwargs.get('categorynamee'))
```

and change your urls and add `^` infront

```
url(r'^new/$',views.CreatePost.as_view(),name='create'),
url(r'^by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)',views.UserPosts.as_view(),name='for_user'),
url(r'^by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.PostDetail.as_view(),name='single'),
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.DeletePost.as_view(),name='delete'),
```

Comment: Thank you, for pointing that out. Still, the problem persists.

Comment: did you change the urls file? and can you show the url in which its getting redirected to after clicking?

Comment: that's because 'for_user' is always true, with or without second parameter.

Comment: I have realized that I have to rethink about the flow and views to make the expected behavior.